# Swift-Add disclosure indicator to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm new to iOS. I had 2 Table View Controllers and I want user to click on 1 cell to navigate to the other Controllers.

However here you can see the sign ">" next to the item, same as in Settings app in iOS 8.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html

But I cannot add Navigation Item to a cell and no matter what segue I use the '>' doesn't show up.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First things first. If you need navigation between view controllers, you need to embed the first view controller in a navigation controller. Each navigation controller maintains a stack on which you can push view controllers. Please refer to the navigation controller documentation. If you want the '>' show up by default, goto the storyboard, click on the cell, goto the fourth tab on the right hand side, select the accessory as 'Disclosure Indicator'.

Comment: It should be Disclosure Indicator instead of None. I submitted that for peer reviewed

Comment: **ATTENTION!** The real option you want is `Disclosure Indicator`, **not** `None`. Simple mistake but too minor to submit an edit.

Comment: I've made the edit to reflect the comments above. I don't think it's a minor edit since it basically changes the answer (which is marked accepted) from wrong to right.

Answer (score 85):

That arrow isn't a `UINavigationItem`; it's a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`.

To add that `UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.disclosureIndicator` "arrow" to your cell's accessory view, add this line:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
```

And then to perform a specific action when that accessory view is tapped, implement [`tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:).

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott It worked for me but how to change the indicator position and its color programmatically ?
for example closer to the cell's label

Comment: @MohammadEliassAlhusain To change color for indicators set the cell tintColor i.e. `cell.tintColor = .red`

Comment: @NitinNain Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Now it has changed to `UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.disclosureIndicator`.

Answer (score 21):

In Swift 4 and Swift 5 this would be:

```
cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

You can also set it in IB if appropriate: Attributes Inspector > Table View Cell > Accessory.